# Elastic Search shard reallocation settings based on CPU utilization

Tags: elasticsearch

We have a elastic search cluster with 28 nodes . Though the number of shards per node is almost same we are frequently observing CPU utilisation/load average on approx 5 nodes is always high while all remaining nodes having very less load average .

What we are suspecting is it could be due to search/scroll operations on the shards hosted on those 5 nodes is relatively high compared to the shards hosted on the other nodes .

Will there be any other reason for this ? Also is there a shard reallocation setting based on CPU usage/load average of the node ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Did you check for any additional processes running on these high load nodes other than the rest of the 23 nodes?
2. Are the hardware configurations on these high load nodes are similar to the rest of the nodes?

Elasticsearch's default shard distribution evenly distributes the shards across all the nodes. This happens automatically without any specific user intervention. If this is not happening, there must be some settings at the cluster's end which are preventing shard balancing.

You should look if the `routing.allocation.include` and `routing.allocation.exclude` settings are present in `GET _cluster/settings/`

```
{
  "persistent" : {
    "cluster" : {
      "routing" : {
        "allocation" : {
          "include" : {
            "_ip" : "xx.xx.xx.xx"
          },
          "enable" : "all",
          "exclude" : {
            "_host" : "xxxxxxx",
            "_ip" : "xx.xx.xx.xx"
          }
        }
      },
      "max_shards_per_node" : "xxxx"
    },
    "search" : {
      "max_buckets" : "xxxx",
      "max_open_scroll_context" : "xxxx"
    },
    "xpack" : {
      "monitoring" : {
        "collection" : {
          "enabled" : "true"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "transient" : { }
}
```

If yes, then you should configure the exclusion or inclusion based on your requirements.

Additionally, you should check your cluster settings for any relocation related configurations were added.

You can check for more details [here](https://opster.com/guides/elasticsearch/capacity-planning/elasticsearch-shard-allocation-is-unbalanced/)

Update :

There is also a possible chance that there is a higher volume of search/scroll operations on the shards hosted on those nodes.
To confirm this, you can use Elasticsearch's node stats API to get detailed information about the CPU usage, indexing, and search operations for each node in the cluster. e.g.

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_nodes/node_name/stats?pretty'
```

Comment: There is no issue with shard distribution, my question is though shards are evenly distributed load average/CPU utilisation is more some node . Btw we dont have any other extra processes running on those nodes. All nodes are of same configurations

Comment: I have updated my answer with one more possible issue. One more question, how is the node role defined on these 28 nodes? @SandeepLade

Comment: All are data nodes

Comment: what is the output of curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_cat/master?v=true'